# DocuSign Rest API: Signer can sign a tab which is for a different recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a simple scenario with the DocuSign REST API as follows:

1. I have 2 signers, Signer1 and Signer2
2. A document is sent to Signer1 to review and sign
3. Signer 2 is notified and reviews the document and signs below where Signer1 signed

I have this working in order except that when Signer1 reviews the document they see Signer2's tab and have to sign for Signer2 as well. The tabs in the document have different names and I am adding the relevant AnchorStrings to the event notification.

Here is my code:

```
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.Email = txtRecipientEmail;
            signer.Name = txtRecipientName;
            signer.RecipientId = "1";           
            signer.RoleName = "Candidate";
            signer.RoutingOrder = "1";

            // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
            signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();

            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere.AnchorString = "PleaseSignHere";
            signHere.AnchorXOffset = "-2";
            signHere.AnchorYOffset = "0";
            signHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
            signHere.AnchorUnits = "inches";
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);                     

            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned>();
            DateSigned dateSigned = new DateSigned();
            dateSigned.DocumentId = "1";
            dateSigned.AnchorString = "DateSignedHere";
            dateSigned.AnchorXOffset = "0";
            dateSigned.AnchorYOffset = "0";
            dateSigned.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
            dateSigned.AnchorUnits = "inches";
            dateSigned.Bold = "true";            
            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(dateSigned);

            // add another signer
            Signer signer2 = new Signer();
            signer2.Email = txtRecipientEmail2;
            signer2.Name = txtRecipientName2;
            signer2.RecipientId = "2";
            signer2.RoleName = "Referee";
            signer2.RoutingOrder = "2";

            signer2.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer2.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();

            SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere();
            signHere2.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere2.AnchorString = "RefPleaseSignHere";
            signHere2.AnchorXOffset = "-2";
            signHere2.AnchorYOffset = "0";
            signHere2.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
            signHere2.AnchorUnits = "inches";
            signer2.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere2);

            signer2.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned>();
            DateSigned dateSigned2 = new DateSigned();
            dateSigned2.DocumentId = "1";
            dateSigned2.AnchorString = "RefDateSignedHere";
            dateSigned2.AnchorXOffset = "0";
            dateSigned2.AnchorYOffset = "0";
            dateSigned2.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
            dateSigned2.AnchorUnits = "inches";
            dateSigned2.Bold = "true";           
            signer2.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(dateSigned2);

            envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer2);
```

I must be missing something!

Answer (score 1):

The anchorString for *Signer1* is also present in anchorString for *Signer2*.

- PleaseSignHere
- Ref**PleaseSignHere**

This is causing *Signer1* tabs to be additionally placed at *Signer2* tab location.

---

**Solution**

- Set the `AnchorMatchWholeWord` property to true.

or

- Use unique anchorStrings which do not overlap.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Please mark the answer as accepted if it addressed your question. Lets know if you have any additional questions.